# Hide the Nav Bar When the Pop Up Opens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Have a Landing Page.

The Mobile Has a Fixed Nav Bar in the Bottom Section.

Also Have a Pop-Up Form That Opens As a Result of a Click.

How Can We Ensure That This Nav Bar Is Closed When the Form Is Opened?

It Blocks the Send Button.

https://filexus.com/landing/

Can We Do This With JavaScript?

Nav Bar:

```
<div class="navbar1">
    <a href="#" class="product-action-btn-1" title="Quick View" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"></i>Take an Offer</a>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the css `z-index` instead of javascript.

Right now you have that bottom nav bar with `z-index: 9999`, but your .modal z-index is 1060, so if you want the modal to render on top, all you have to do is set the .modal z-index to a higher number than the .navbar1 z-index.

So the easiest fix is simply:

```
.modal{ z-index: 10000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best off creating a class to hide the element, then toggling that when you call the modal or dismiss it.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('navbar1')[0].classList.add('hidden')
document.getElementsByClassName('navbar1')[0].classList.remove('hidden')
```

You could also use [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) if dismissal happens within the same function as the call.

Answer (score 0):

Hide your Navbar when clicked.

```
<script>
function hideNav() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("navbar1").style.display = "none";
}
</script>


<div class="navbar1">
    <a onclick="hideNav()"  href="#" class="product-action-btn-1" title="Quick View" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"></i>Take an Offer</a>
</div>
```